# Adding filtered data from database into a grid view

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to optimize this nested foreach and if statement function for work. My code is retrieving data from a SSMS SQL database with thousands of fields from multiple tables of data, moving them to lists and then looping through the lists to retrieve the data. It is moving all the data to a data grid view to be exported to an excel sheet.

Any ideas on how I can make it run faster?

```
foreach (Calibrations calibration in Model.PostCalibrationsList)
        {
            if (calibration.Job_No == textBox1.Text)
            {
                foreach (Instruments instrument in Model.InstrumentsList)
                {
                    if (calibration.Inst_ID == instrument.Inst_ID)
                    {
                        foreach (Proc_InstInfo info in Model.Proc_InstInfoList)
                        {
                            foreach (ProcQRef qRef in Model.ProcQRefList)
                            {
                                if (calibration.Inst_ID == instrument.Inst_ID)
                                {
                                    if (instrument.Procedure == info.Proc_No.ToString() && instrument.Procedure == qRef.Procedure.ToString())
                                    {
                                        ex.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(calibration.Order_No, calibration.Inst_ID, instrument.Description, calibration.Cust_Ref, instrument.Manufacturer, instrument.Model_No, instrument.Serial_No, info.Comm1, calibration.Calibration_Required, qRef.StockCode, calibration.Cert_No, info.Proc_No);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you add a description of what your code is actually doing? All I can gather is you're adding *something* to a data grid view. And make your title match what it's doing, not your concern about the code. How often is this snippet of code called? Perhaps you should show us the entire function, because as it stands you're just looping through every list and adding it to the data grid view, not really much room for optimization.

Comment: 1) Please refer to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
2) What is the reason you want to optimize this code? Is something running particularly slow?

Comment: yeah it takes about 20 seconds to open the data grid view form

Comment: Your title should describe what your code does, not what you want out of a review.

Comment: I think you have a copy/paste bug. There are two `if (calibration.Inst_ID == instrument.Inst_ID)` nested within each other. Obviously, only the first one matters.

Comment: Also, LINQ can be your friend here: `foreach (Calibrations calibration in Model.PostCalibrationsList.Where(cal => cal.Job_No == textBox1.Text))` will filter out records without the need for nested `if`s.

Comment: This is not a forum and we do not add any _[solved]_ etc, marking an answer is enougth... even though it's off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you say you're fetching the data from an SQL database, you should use it. It should be *much* faster to filter the data with a `WHERE` in the SQL query than to serialise it, deserialise it, and then filter it without the benefit of any indexes.

Given this tiny fragment of code it's impossible to give more detailed advice on how to do that. It depends enormously on the ORM you're using.

Comment: i tried using where statements within the sql query and it made the process much faster (20 seconds down to 1-2 seconds), thanks!